# Undefined index error for session on loading of page

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, session

I am getting error "Undefined index: Msg in Employee.php " when am deleting the employee.
Am trying to display the session value from employeedb.php.
Here is my employee.php. Here am trying to display session message inside the div "divGuestRegisterContainer"

```
<?php
require_once("includes.php");
<div id="divGuestRegisterContainer" >
<b>
<?php   
if($_SESSION["Msg"]!="")
{
?>
<ul>
<li>
<b><?php 
echo $_SESSION["Msg"];
?>
</b>
</li>
</ul>
<?php
$_SESSION["Msg"]="";
}
?>
</b>
<ul>
<li>
<span style="width:120px;">Employee Name :</span>
<input type="text" name="txt_empname" id="txt_empname" class="textbox" value="<?php echo $emp_name;?>" />                       
</li>
<li >
<input type='button' id='btnDelete' name='btnDelete' class='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteEmployee()' style='margin-left:10px;width:85px;display:inline' />
</li>
</ul>
</div>
?>
```

I am passing the $_SESSION["Msg"] value from employeedb.php to employee.php
this is my employeedb.php

```
<?php
require_once("includes.php");
$genObj=new general();
$type=$_GET["type"];
$emp_id=$_POST["HFEmpID"];
if($type=="delete")
{
mysql_query("UPDATE employee SET del_flag=1 WHERE emp_id=".$emp_id."");
$_SESSION["Msg"]="Employee details deleted successfully!";
}
 header( 'Location:Employee.php');
?>
```

When am clicking on delete button , am calling this javascript function,
this is my javascript function.

```
function deleteEmployee()
{
var del = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Employee?");
if (del == true)
{
document.forms[0].action="employeeDB.php?type=delete";
document.forms[0].submit();
}
else
{
document.forms[0].action="employeeDB.php";
}
}
```

this is my includes.php where I started session already

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
//Session Starts    
require_once("config/config.php");      
require_once("config/dbcon/dbcon.php");
require_once("classes/csGeneral.php");
require_once("classes/csPager.php");
require_once("classes/csImageFunctions.php");
require_once("classes/striptag.php");
/* $_SESSION["returnURL"]=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];  */
$genCheckUser=new general();
$genCheckUser->getUserIDCookie();
?>
```

Comment: Have you started session session_start() ?

Comment: yes I had already started seesion in includes.php

Comment: passing the value for $emp_id is missing.

Comment: Am passing the value here for $emp_id using a hidden field, I didnt post the full code. I just need to display the session message after deleting the employee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you just echoed `$_SESSION['Msg']`

```
<b><?php  echo $_SESSION["Msg"]; ?> </b>
```

this will have error at the start because you havent set a value for this one because you
havent done delete before so in order to remove the error

So you must add the condition that if $_SESSION['Msg'] is not yet set dont echo it..

```
<b><?php  if(!empty($_SESSION['Msg'])){ echo $_SESSION["Msg"];} ?> </b>
```

Comment: yes I already started session in Includes.php which contain all my database connections

Comment: where did you pass a value for $emp_id?

Comment: @kali, I didnt post the full code, I just have problem with session only, I am able to delete now. Here am getting $emp_idfrom a hidden field

Comment: try this one for us to see if seesion variable is set.

Comment: Thank you Kali , I tried that code still that error is coming ("Empty Session
Notice: Undefined index: Msg inEmployee.php")

Comment: did you have anything that will destroy sessions?

Comment: yes , am using session_destroy(); session_unset(); in my logout page . but it will work only if am clicking on logout link

Comment: would you mind to comment that out first then try this one again.. I think theres an issue againts that it automatically destroy session everytime you deleted a record..

Comment: @kali,I tried debuging as you told, but the exact problem is that, whenever am loading employee.php, I am getting this error as default, but after deleting the employee that error will be going

Comment: oh i see because  at first $_SESSION['Msg'] is not yet set so you must have a condition .. ill edit it

Comment: Oh thank you kali you are absolutely correct. Now error is not coming thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

You have to check if the variable indeed exists before checking if its empty.

So change line 6 to:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['Msg']))
```

From the PHP manual :

> isset — Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
ob_start();
```

should be:

```
ob_start();
session_start();
.
.
.
ob_flush();       <------- last statement
```